# Why is my long long overflowing / turning negative on integer division?

Tags: c++, integer

```
for (long long j = factored_num / 3; j > 2 || factored_num != 1; j -= 2) {
```

On a 64-bit computer, I'm trying to factor a number. This code works perfectly fine when `long long j = factored_num`, but when I do integer division, `cout << j` shows that `j` is negative -- I'm assuming it overflows. How can I fix this?

I've tried `3LL`, `j-= 2LL`, etc. in case it was a type problem. Again, it definitely has to do with the division part, but I'm not familiar enough with data types to immediately get the problem.

Comment: What is the type of `factored_num`?

Comment: and `factored_num` initial value? Did you initialized it?

Comment: You have to show us the whole loop. By the way, it is better to look for factors in increasing order, because each factor found decreases `factored_num`, and small factors can be found faster than large factors. Also, you only have to search up to the square root of `factored_num` (`j * j <= factored_num`), not `factored_num / 3`.

Comment: Hm, if the divisor is `3LL`, than the division should be done in `long long` no matter what type `factored_num` is.

Comment: And regardless of the types (as long as they are integral), `factored_num / 3` cannot overflow, and will be positive if `factored_num` is positive.  Supposing his description of the problem is correct, the only way `j` can be negative is if `factored_num` is an unsigned integral type, and `factored_num / 3` is not representable in a `long long`.

Comment: @JamesKanze: `j` can also be negative if `factored_num` never becomes 1 in the body of the loop (which is still not shown), which I suspect is the real problem.

Comment: Sorry -- factored_num is also long long. Should have clarified that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem could be the final condition. You loop **while** `j` is more than 2 **or** `factored_num` is not 1, so if `factored_num` does not become one, the loop will not end and j will continue to decrement to negative numbers.

I'd expect the condition to be `j > 2 && factored_num != 1`, that is you want to **end** if `j` is 2 or less (why 2; 2 is a valid factor) or factored_num is 1 (and therefore does not have any more factors).